# Looping ignora o resto do programa

Tags: python, loop

Eu estava escrevendo um programa pra calcular as taxas do PayPal pra poder ajudar uns amigos meus, mas no meu trecho anti falhas do usuário, se o input não for o especificado, o looping simplesmente ignora o resto do programa e fecha. Qual o problema? EDIT: Também percebo que o else é ignorado

```
while True:
    response = input("Você quer calcular o quanto vai receber, ou o quanto precisa ser pago?\nResponda com recebido ou pago: \n")
    if response == 'pago' or 'recebido':
        break
    else:
        print("Algo deu errado. Responda especificamente com 'pago' ou 'recebido")
try:
    if response == "recebido":
        given = input("Ponha o quanto será pago: ")
        given = float(given)
        received = float(given * 0.9521) - 0.60
        print('O recebido será ',received,'.')
    elif response == "pago":
        received = input("Ponha o quanto quer receber: ")
        received = float(received)
        given = float(received + 0.60) / 0.9521
        print('Você precisará pagar ',given,'.')
except:
    print("Algo deu errado, tente outra vez. Lembre-se de usar pontos '.', e não vírgulas ','")
```

Comment: Não era pra continuar loopando infinitamente até ser o certo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problema

Você colocou uma string na segunda condição, assim o Python interpreta como um resultado verdadeiro:

```
if response == 'pago' or 'recebido':
```

## Solução

Você deve colocar a variável de novo para comparar com a string "recebido".

```
if response == 'pago' or response == 'recebido':
```

Python interpreta uma string não vazia como um resultado verdadeiro, como você usou um "or" e a segunda condição foi verdadeira ele entrou no if e parou o while por causa do break, e não entrou em mais nenhum if posterior dando a entender que o programa foi fechado imediatamente.

## Resultado

```
while True:
    response = input("Você quer calcular o quanto vai receber, ou o quanto precisa ser pago?\nResponda com recebido ou pago: \n")
    if response == 'pago' or response == 'recebido':
        break
    else:
        print("Algo deu errado. Responda especificamente com 'pago' ou 'recebido")
try:
    if response == "recebido":
        given = input("Ponha o quanto será pago: ")
        given = float(given)
        received = float(given * 0.9521) - 0.60
        print('O recebido será ',received,'.')
    elif response == "pago":
        received = input("Ponha o quanto quer receber: ")
        received = float(received)
        given = float(received + 0.60) / 0.9521
        print('Você precisará pagar ',given,'.')
except:
    print("Algo deu errado, tente outra vez. Lembre-se de usar pontos '.', e não vírgulas ','")
```

[Executar](https://repl.it/repls/BrokenOffshoreStack)